# Can you run the same application and code on Android and Linux?

Tags: android, linux

I'm looking to build a new app written in Java, can I write one code that can be executed both on an OS running Linux and OS running android? Or do I need to write two different codes one for each system?

Comment: In theory, if its the same version of Java and has the same libraries installed, then it should just work. In practice, most software is different for mobile than for PC just because of the different environments, like limited CPU and storage.  Firefox on Android was rewritten to be lighter and faster, for example.

Comment: So if I’m looking to build an app that will be used on phones running android and/or phones running Linux the same code should work for both?

Comment: Linux phones???

Comment: Yes or computer

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically **yes**.

Android apps run in a [Dalvik Virtual Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_(software)), that comes with a Java language implementation that compiles down to Dalvik bytecode, but not to JVM bytecode. So, the code has to be written in Java or some language that compiles to Dalvik VM bytecode that uses the Android API.

However, the virtual machine runs on top of the underlying Linux OS, and there are ways to call native code. See [NDK documentation](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html).

So, it is technically possible to run native Linux programs on Android, as there is a Linux kernel running beneath everything.

Comment: I'd demand proof of concept ...because unless linking against the NDK, you won't run anything.